# Force on bolt holding up jet engine on plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I am to solve the following:

> A jet engine of mass $m$ is fastened to the fuselage of a passenger jet by a bolt. During flight, the plane encounters turbulence, which suddenly imparts an upward vertical acceleration of $2.60\mathrm{~m/s^2}$ to the plane. Calculate the force on the bolt.

Since the jet engine weighs $9.81m\mathrm{~N}$ and the engine has a net force of $2.60m\mathrm{~N}$, the force on the bolt is either $(9.81+2.60)m\mathrm{~N}$ or $(9.81-2.60)m\mathrm{~N}$, but I do not understand which.

I would like to draw a free-body diagram to help me understand the problem, but I am not sure how to in this case.

**UPDATE:**

Here is what I have. Suppose the mass of the fuselage is $M$ and the mass of the bolt is negligible. Then the free-body diagram is:

[image: free-body-diagram]

where

- $F_{FA}=2.60M$ is the force on the fuselage by the air
- $F_{AF}=Mg$ is the force on the air by the fuselage
- $F_{BE}$ is the force on bolt by the engine
- $F_{EA}=2.60m$ is the force on the engine by the air
- $F_{AE}=mg$ is the force on the air by the engine

However, I am not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Like the tag says, make a [free-body-diagram] first.

Comment: Something trivial bugs me here-it's fastened to the *fuselage?*

Comment: Probably, the meanings you gave to $F_{EA}$ and $F_{AE}$ are misleading. First, $F_{AE}$ is simply the weight of the jet engine (that acts on the bolt, and then, through the bolt, on the wing/fuselage and then, at last, on the air when the plane is flying). Second, the air turbulence doesn't presumably lift directly the engine but it lift the wing first. Then, the wing wants the engine to lift, through the bolt, with an acceleration of $2.6$ m/s$^2$. Then the Newton third law... the opposite force... and the solution I gave you... I hope to made myself clearer now! Godspeed!

Answer (score 1):

Since the turbulence acts like an upward vertical acceleration, the bolt will experiment an additional force of $2.6\times m$ N downward. That is, the engine wants to move, by inertia, in a linear motion; since for the turbulence the wing pulls it up, the engine reacts exerting a force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to that due to the turbulence (Newton's third law of the motion). Then the total force the bolt will hold is $(9.81+2.6)m$ N.

The only thing you should understand is the reaction mechanism to the turbulence. Then, the free-body motion diagram is quite trivial.